# How to download zip file through browser Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, zip

I am trying to zip some images as user-selected.up to now I have come up with a solution for zipping.My problem is after I zip the relevant data to zip file how can I download it through the browser.i have tried different methods still not working.when I create zip it stored in the public folder.how can I download the zip file from there through the browser?

Here is my code

```
$photos = json_decode(Input::get('photos'));
$dir = time();
foreach ($photos as $file) {
   /* Log::error(ImageHandler::getUploadPath(false, $file));*/
   $imgName = last(explode('/', $file));
   $path = public_path('downloads/' . $dir);
    if (!File::exists($path)) {
        File::makeDirectory($path, 0775, true);
    }
    ImageHandler::downloadFile($file, $path . '/' . $imgName);
}

$rootPath = realpath($path);
$zip_file = 'Photos.zip';
$public_dir = public_path();
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open($zip_file, ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);
/** @var SplFileInfo[] $files */
$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
         new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($rootPath),
         RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
);

foreach ($files as $name => $file1) {
    // Skip directories (they would be added automatically)
    if (!$file1->isDir()) {
        // Get real and relative path for current file
        $filePath = $file1->getRealPath();
        $relativePath = substr($filePath, strlen($rootPath) + 1);
        // Add current file to archive
        $zip->addFile($filePath, $relativePath);
     }
}

// Zip archive will be created only after closing object
$zip->close();
$fileurl = public_path()."/Photos.zip";
if (file_exists($fileurl))
{
      return Response::download($fileurl, 'Photos.zip', ['Content-Length: '. filesize($fileurl)]);
} else {
      exit('Requested file does not exist on our server!');
}
```

In response i'm getting something like this:
[image]

Comment: try this return response()->download(yourfile name or location of file);

Comment: @bipin  its not working

Comment: Try: `return response()->download($fileurl, $zipFileName, $headers)->deleteFileAfterSend(true);`

Comment: @HirenGohel not working

Comment: Are you trying to load the file via ajax?

Comment: @joseph  try this $fullPath = public_path('datafiles/APPL').'/'.$data->latestresume;
        return response()->download($fullPath);  here $data->latestresume this i m getting from database

Comment: Where is your file stored in public folder? Can you please show us the full public path?

Comment: @HirenGohel this is the path C:\wamp64\www\website\public/Photos.zip

Comment: Try: `return Response::download($fileurl, 'Photos.zip', array('Content-Type' => 'application/octet-stream','Content-Length: '. filesize($fileurl))); 
`

Comment: @HirenGohel You can vote up my answer too.. :p ;)

Comment: @HirenGohel still not working.

Comment: Have you any errors in your console?

Comment: @HirenGohel  no i dont have any errors.but in response there is something,i ll update it

Comment: Ok, also try to `dd($fileurl);` in your `if (file_exists($fileurl))
        {` condition. Check that if it is true?

Comment: @HirenGohel i have updated the question

Comment: The problem is you're trying to load the file via AJAX, which you can't do the way that you're trying to do it. Are you trying to load the file via ajax?

Comment: @HirenGohel yes .if not how can i do this

Comment: @joseph, at top of your code input::get won't work if you try to upload file change it to input::file

Comment: @bipin this is about download

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to load the file via AJAX, which you can't do the way that you're trying to do it.

```
if (file_exists($fileurl)) {
    return Response::download($fileurl, 'Photos.zip', array('Content-Type: application/octet-stream','Content-Length: '. filesize($fileurl)))->deleteFileAfterSend(true);
} else {
    return ['status'=>'zip file does not exist'];
}
```

Change your **javascript** to:

```
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),  self = this;
window.location = window.location.origin+'/download-file/' + this.selected
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: so do i have replace these two lines with my Ajax request

Comment: i have updated code with my javascript can u show me where to change

Comment: I don't think that your ajax code is use for download a file as you posted in your question!!

Comment: is there any way i can achieve this

Comment: @joseph Please see this demo example: https://codepen.io/chrisdpratt/pen/RKxJNo  and accept & upvote my answer with closing this issue!

Comment: still not get fixed.when i am done i l upvote your answer thank you

Comment: @joseph In that example, they just put one button and using ajax calling the file downloaded. I have see it and it's seems working OK. You can put your POST route and your file and it's working!

Comment: Hi, let me know if this fixed now!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
return Response::download($fileurl, 'Photos.zip', ['Content-Length: '. filesize($fileurl)]);
```

to

```
return Response::download($fileurl, 'Photos.zip', array('Content-Type: application/zip','Content-Length: '. filesize($fileurl)));
```

OR

```
return Response::download($fileurl, 'Photos.zip', array('Content-Type: application/octet-stream','Content-Length: '. filesize($fileurl)));
```

Comment: You must be getting some errors. Please update question with the errors.

Comment: there were no errors in console.but something in the response.i have updated the question

Comment: @joseph That is .zip files raw content. You need to reload the view with full filepath to download the file.

Comment: I didnt get you can u exaplain me further more

Comment: Please confirm you're trying to download file using ajax..?

Comment: @joseph Hey, just now you told me that i m using ajax to download a file! How can we solve your question!!

Comment: @HirenGohel im sorry.i just get confused with the data passing ajax.

Answer (score 0):

try this way may be it help. just return you zip file and path name in ajax success
in controller

```
    $fileurl = public_path()."/Photos.zip";
    if (file_exists($fileurl))
    {
        return response()->json($fileurl);
    }
    else
    {
        exit('Requested file does not exist on our server!');
    }
```

then add this line

```
      success: function (data) {
         'download': data.fileurl,
          }
```